# Retrieve permissions of only first level folders in a SharePoint online Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document-library, permissions, pnp-powershell

We have a request from our auditors to provide a csv file, that contains for each document library in a site, unique permissions applied on **only the first level of folders** within the document library, without going into each subfolder.

I've found PnP PowerShell scripts that retrieve security for all subfolders, but couldn't find any for only top level folders.

Comment: Please share PnP PowerShell Script which you are using currently

Comment: As per my knowledge I'm afraid it is impossible.